# Reading the string line of input and use the numbers in them as integer in c++

Tags: c++

As the example below indicates, one kind of input is the specification of a set of vertices V, and set of edges E of the undirected graph. The specification of a set of vertices starts with ’V’, followed by a space, followed by a positive integer, all in one single line. If the integer that follows the V is i, then we assume that the vertices are identified by 0, . . . , i − 1. The specification for a set of edges starts with ’E’. It then has a space, followed by the set of edges in a single line delimited by ’{’ and ’}’. The two vertices of an edge are delimited by ’<’ and ’>’ and separated by a comma. The edges in the set are also separated by a comma. There are no whitespace characters within the { }.

```
V 5
E {<0,4>,<4,1>,<0,3>,<3,4>,<3,2>,<1,3>}
```

My question is What is the best way to read this input?
One way is to read each line as an string and split it. then convert them to int. is there any other better way to read these kind of input in c++ in standard input?

Comment: If you don't care too much about optimising this from a performance point of view, then simply read the line, process the first character (if you have to), then simply replace all of the `"{}<>,"` with white-space, pass to a stringstream and read integers into a vector of pairs from that (that's for the line that starts with `E`, the line starting with `V` is simple enough to deal with as-is).

Comment: The best way is the one you are comfortable writing and maintaining. The best way is the simplest and clearest to read. The best way is the one that doesn't prematurely optimize. The best way is one that accounts for error conditions appropriate for the program's intended purpose.